# Google play displays my app as not compatible on Oneplus two ,Sony Z3 etc

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I want my app to be available only on phone and phablet screens ,thus have the below mentioned tags in my manifest file.

```
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Even though I have screen density upto 640dp as being supported for normal screens,my users on One Plus Two,Sony Z3 etc (1280x1920) are getting 'App not compatible' on Playstore where as the app is compatible on Nexus 6.
How do I get the right combination in the manifest file so that apps are available for all phones but not on tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are going about this in the wrong way:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

will mark you as only working on phones.

Comment: In which case they are a phablet to use your terminology, which you also said you wanted to run on.

Comment: Sorry,I was not clear with my description. By phablets I meant phones with larger screen like Nexus 6 .My app looks is not authored for larger 7' or 10' screens.